# Salesforce Platform license - Not all contact are visible

Tags: profile, sharing, user, licenses, org-wide-defaults

I have a user with Salesforce platform license and the user has been assigned a profile ( salesforce platform license). There is no roles or role hierarchy present. There is public read/write in org wide for accounts and contact is controlled by Parent( Account). Profile has access to all the contact's record type as well. There is no sharing setting in profile level.

My problem - I am unable to see all the contact records( just 8 out of 20,000+) but I am able to see all the account records. I verified the number of contact using sys admin profile.

Why is this behavior? Any Idea?

Comment: what do you mean that you are not able to see all records? Do you have some list view limiting records count?

Comment: I bet screenshot would be helpful to explain your problem

Comment: I am using All view only, that is standard salesforce view.. I do not have a custom view

Comment: Are you sure that you are using standard salesforce view and that it has not been modified or overwritten?

Comment: Yes that correct. I did not modify the list view

Comment: Just an update. I only see contact with accounts associated with it. I do not see contact which do not have a account Name. Any reason for this behaviour for a salesforce platform user license?

Comment: Try to use DataLoader with the same user and export all Contacts. If the output is the same then you will need to provide more details (the screenshot, profile file, etc.)

Comment: The contact does not have view all permission. So when contact is not associated with accounts we don't see the contact not owned by that user